# Customize SQL queries to sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

In my hierarchy_resoponse table have a values with ‘*’ and other values for the hierachy_id

I want to select hierarcy_response table record select hierarchy_id = ‘*’ records as first records and other records later.

Ex -:
Records in my table -:

```
| response_id | hierarchy_id | hierarchy_name
| 1           | HI1          | Hierarchy 1
| 2           | *            | ABC Hierarchy
| 3           | *            | CD Hierarchy 
| 4           | Hie2         | Hierary 2
```

I want to select records as below -:

```
| response_id | hierarchy_id | hierarchy_name
| 2           | *            | ABC Hierarchy
| 3           | *            | CD Hierarchy 
| 1           | HI1          | Hierarchy 1
| 4           | Hie2         | Hierary 2
```

This is my select query -:

```
Select * from hierarchy_response;
```

How I modify this with ‘Order by’ query?

Comment: You'll need to correct your Tag contradiction `mysql`<>`sql-server`, and add a few sample data and show the expected result in order to make your question "work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this,

```
Select * from hierarchy_response
ORDER BY CASE WHEN hierarchy_id = ‘*’ THEN 1
              ELSE 2 END;
```